# How do i add color to an entire Vuetify Data Table row with dynamic headers

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

Good day.

I have a data-table divided by groups with dynamic headers that change depending on whatever months the user choose to obtain information from, so i want to get information from the months of January until April i'll have 5 columns, one with the name of my classifications and 4 related to the months i am searching for.

every group has a row called total that summarizes the expenses of each group for each month and i want to be able to color this entire row with a color of my choosing. How would i go about that, especially when i have dynamic headers that change whenever the user searches for a time period?

```
<v-data-table 
    dense 
    :headers="headers" 
    :items="classifications" 
    item-key="classification"
    group-by="classification_group"
    disable-sort
    hide-default-footer
    disable-pagination
    class="elevation-1"
    >
    <template v-slot:group.header="{items, isOpen, toggle}">
        <th colspan=1000000>
        <v-icon @click="toggle"
            >{{ isOpen ? 'mdi-minus' : 'mdi-plus' }}
        </v-icon>
        {{ items[0].classification_group }}
        </th>
    </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to apply a `class` to the "total" row's `tr` element and have CSS that is applied to this `class`.

So in my `v-data-table` `template`, I have a `v-if` that detects if the `tr` element is for a "total" row and, if so, applies a `table-row-total` class.

Then, in that component's `<style>` section I apply something like:

```
 .my-table-name .v-data-table tr.table-row-total {
    background-color: #ffff00 !important;
 }
```

You may want to double-check [the Vuetify data tables API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#api), but to the best of my knowledge, I don't know of a more sophisticated way in Vuetify to handle styling 'special case' rows in a datatable -- so, the method above worked fine for me.